# Best way to write audio files to google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm processing an input audio file from a google bucket using ffmpeg and writing the output to another google bucket. For this, I'm initially writing it to the `/tmp` folder and then uploading the file to the google bucket using `blob.upload_from_filename(local_path)`. However I read that writing to `/tmp` increases RAM usage and I'd like to know of a better way (perhaps writing directly to the google bucket).

I considered signed urls, but whilst they're useful reading the audio files from the input bucket, I couldn't find a way to write to a file using it's signed url.

Answer (score 1):

Google's documentation for GCS for [Streaming transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#code-samples) for Python suggests using [resumable uploads](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-resumable-media/latest/resumable_media/requests.html#resumable-uploads)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that. Will try it out :)

Comment: I've not used this with Python but it's likely your best bet. There has been some discussion about supporting streaming [up|down]loads with the Python GCS client: e.g. [Streaming upload/download for blobs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2871)

Answer (score 0):

Writing to /tmp does not increase RAM consumption unless you have mounted a RAMDISK to /tmp which some distributions do by default. To find out if /tmp is a RAMDISK, see e.g. http://linuxintro.org/wiki/Ramdisk

If you do not want to create a local file at all, I'd use upload_from_string as suggested in [Upload file to cloud storage from request without saving it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116860/upload-file-to-cloud-storage-from-request-without-saving-it-locally)

Comment: Well, `upload_from_string` can't be used for audio files, right?

Comment: @TonyStark, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116860/upload-file-to-cloud-storage-from-request-without-saving-it-locally it is used for BLOBS