# Upload file to cloud storage from request without saving it locally

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, python-requests, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a file to google cloud storage using the API which I build on Flask (python) but I don't want to save the file locally. Directly take the file from request and upload it to cloud storage.

## Upload to GCS method

```
def upload_to_bucket(blob_name, path_to_file):
    """ Upload data to a bucket"""
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(path_to_file)

    #returns a public url
    return blob.public_url
```

## Get the file object from request body

> file = request.files['file']

This is how I am calling the method

```
url = upload_to_bucket(file.name, file)
```

But here it returns with Attributer error. I tried file.value, file.file but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you check documentation from google? [Using Cloud Storage  |  App Engine flexible environment for Python docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 2):

Use the **upload_from_string** method.

```
file = request.files['file']
blob = bucket.blob(file.filename)
blob.upload_from_string(file.read(), content_type=file.content_type)
```

[API Documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html)